# "Check Pods Manifest.lock" fails Every time i download Project from github account

Tags: xcode7

I am getting following error every time i download project from Github.I tried every other solution found on google but couldn't succeed.

diff: /Users//Documents//Pods/../Podfile.lock: No such file or directory
diff: /Users//Documents//Pods/Manifest.lock: No such file or directory
error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation.

Comment: please specify which commands you are trying to run.

Comment: I have used following commands:
-sudo gem install cocoa pods
-$ cd <Poject location> pod init
-Opened the podfile (open -a Xcode Podfile) and added the podlin.
- pod install

Answer (score -1):

Did you already create a podile?

With cocoapods installed, take the following steps:

- Open a terminal window, and $ cd into your project directory (cd ~/Path/To/Folder/Containing/your/app)
- Create a Podfile by running $ pod init
- Open the podfile (open -a Xcode Podfile) and add the podline and save the file, for example:

> pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.0'

- Run $ pod install in your project directory
- Open App.xcworkspace

Please find a more extended guide [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/97014/use-cocoapods-with-swift)

Hope this helps!